# How to use random SALT for password hashing?

Tags: php, encryption, sha256

I've been looking at some other topics on stackoverflow but they are way too complex for the beginner me. I was wondering, how is it possible to generate a random salt?

Let's say I generate a random salt and concatenate it to my password(which has been converted to SHA256). How will I go about to check for the salt when the user logs in, in this case where a random salt is generated and concatenated to the pass?

I would appreciate if you could give me a simple code snippet on how it would work.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not use [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/function.password-hash) (requires PHP>=5.5) or its [userland equivalent](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) (for earlier versions) to do all that for you?

Comment: @MarkBaker I was thinking of something like this:

$salt = //random; and concatenate this with the pass. But I was wondering how to I check this when the user logs in, given this salt is random?

Comment: You store the salt with the hash in the database, its only random when its created

Answer (score 2):

From [password_verify](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php):

> [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/function.password-hash) returns the algorithm, cost and salt as part of the returned hash.

In other words, the salt is handled for you if you use these two functions; you don't need to worry about it.

Check those two manual pages for code examples (I'd paste them here, but the manual's not going anywhere and it's probably best to read the entire pages).

Comment: Thanks. Checking this out.

Comment: Go with these (or the compatibility implementation for older php version Mark Baker linked). These are well written and follow best practices.